# How to detect that an update of my app is available on google play?

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way I can programmatically check if there is an update of my app on google play so I notify users? I know android google play has an automatic notifications but I would like to use my own notification/pop up message for update availability (sort of like what Viber app does).

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a JSON file on your server containing the `android:versionCode` of the last version of you app. Retrieveng and comparing the version code will not be really complicated.

This information is not displayed on the Google Play Store. So a hacky script will not be able to retrieve this. Only the `android:versionName` is displayed.

Comment: >"This information is not displayed on the Google Play Store" — now (at least when viewing from desktop browser) it's there.

Comment: @SargeBorsch I was just saying that the versionCode is not displayed on the Google Play web page of the app, but you can of course do something with the versionName.

Comment: OK, I understood now.

Answer (score 3):

There is no API that provides this information. If your application has [INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in your Manifest, then you could create a server which returns your current version number. If it differs from the installed version, then you could create the custom Notification.

Comment: just add this logic  create a service which  register your current version number if it differs then pop up a notification.